# Using a RestTemplate to parse HATEOAS response

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-hateoas, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing out a HATEOAS response from a Spring RepositoryRestResource.  Admittedly, I'm a bit new with some of these libs.

my repository is working and generating a good response as follows:

```
{
_embedded: {
tracks: [
{
trackName: "Oreville Kart Club",
latitude: "40.5212757",
longitude: "-75.6920605",
address1: "532 Old Topton Rd",
address2: "",
city: "Mertztown",
state: "PA",
zip: "19539-0000",
phoneNumber: "123-456-7890",
administratorId: "1",
locale: null,
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks/1"
},
track: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks/1"
}
}
},
{
trackName: "Oakland Valley Race Park(OVRP)",
latitude: "41.474944",
longitude: "-74.616462",
address1: "305 Oakland Valley Rd",
address2: "",
city: "Cuddebackville",
state: "NY",
zip: "12729-0000",
phoneNumber: "976-432-1234",
administratorId: "2",
locale: null,
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks/2"
},
track: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks/2"
}
}
}
]
},
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks"
},
profile: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/profile/tracks"
},
search: {
href: "http://localhost:10100/track-service/tracks/search"
}
},
page: {
size: 20,
totalElements: 2,
totalPages: 1,
number: 0
}
}
```

Now here is my code, which I think is correct.  I've done my best to follow a few examples I've found on the web.

```
@RestController
@EnableZuulProxy
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiGatewayController {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/tracks")
    public Collection<Pair<Long, String>> listTracks() {

        ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Track>> ptr = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Track>>() { } ;     

        ResponseEntity<Resources<Track>> entity = restTemplate.exchange("http://track-service/tracks", HttpMethod.GET, null, ptr);

        return entity.getBody()
                .getContent()
                .stream()
                .map(t -> Pair.of(t.getTrackId(), t.getTrackName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    class Track {
        private Long trackId;
        private String trackName;
        public Long getTrackId() {
            return trackId;
        }
        public void setTrackId(Long trackId) {
            this.trackId = trackId;
        }
        public String getTrackName() {
            return trackName;
        }
        public void setTrackName(String trackName) {
            this.trackName = trackName;
        }
    }
}
```

The odd thing is I am getting the following error, I'm just not sure why.  It seems that jackson is unable to parse the response, but its a standard HATEOS HAL response

```
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.apex.microservice.ApiGatewayController$Track: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@27f652c; line: 4, column: 7] (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.apex.microservice.ApiGatewayController$Track: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@27f652c; line: 4, column: 7] (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"])
```

I'm not sure it it is a type erasure problem, or a problem with the constructor.  I believe my ParameterizedTypeRequest is correct, and I'm not sure what constructor is desired here.  I have tried a few variations to no avail. If anyone can enlighten me here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The answer is in the error. Track needs to have a default constructor and/or be public.

Comment: I tried that, it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: `Track` is not public.

Comment: Just wanted to share the solution to my problem.  Making Track public, and explicitly adding a public null constructor did not do the trick.  It was a scoping issue.  I moved the "Track" object so it was no longer an inner class and this worked just fine.

Comment: Making it public static would have probably worked as well. I've done it many times.

Comment: Interesting, wont making it static create threading issues?

Comment: no, the class is static, not the instances.